InputStream.available() strange behavior
I have the source code of a running project - that is unfortunately already deployed to customers.
The following Java code is running the update process :
public void downloadChanges() throws IOException {
  try (InputStream is = WebClient.doRawRequest(HttpMethod.GET, machinePath + "/update/", null)) { //IOexception is thrown outside
            if (is.available() == 0) {
                logInfo("Nothing downloaded");
            }
            
                   //continue with downloaded stuff
        }
    }

I now need to code a new backend for that.
I do not know why the heck is.available() always returns 0.
I found out about InputStream.available() doesn't work
but as changing the java code is no option here I opened a new thread.
I tried adding some debugging code for testing in the Java Code, so it would look like this :
           if (is.available() == 0) {
                byte[] data = is.readNBytes(2048 * 1024);
                String content = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(content);
            System.out.println("Nothing downloaded.");
            return;
       }

In this case, I get the complete and correct answer by my php software.
Anyone got ideas how to set up my php correctly to work with is.available?
I can't change the java code and need to get my server running, no matter how hacky this will be.
We can't visit every customer all over the world....

The available() method is not intended to do what you want to do with it. There is no way to setup the php software to make the method do what you want. If you want to save the content of an InputStream to a local file, just use Files.copy, if you want read it into a byte array, use is.readAllBytes()

InputStream is abstract and InputStream.available() always returns 0, as per javadoc. is.readNBytes is a blocking read for up to 2MB. My guess is you should look into the definition of WebClient that extends InputStream and implements all what you need.
Also, do you have some code already interacting with this Java so you might have an idea of what it's expecting from the Java code you're showing -- but are not allowed to alter?

You need to fix the error in your code. That's all

I cannot alter the java code because the java code was made by another company and got already shipped to our customers - so there is no way to provide an update without a working update function. (because of the use of available()) ......
Thank you very much for your answer

WebClient.doRawRequest() will send the request to the server and immediately return the InputStream. Since the InputStream will only have data available once the server has processed the request and delivered data a call to is.available() will return 0 (since at that moment reading data will block). There is nothing you can do on the PHP side to change this.

Then the customers might well either complain or worse, silently drop away

If this code is part of the update function (and so there is no way to provide an update without a working update function implies that) then you have no working update function - except shipping new Java code to your customers.

So, you can retrace the problem in your local environment (where you inserted the debug code) which implies that testing the code just a single time before deploying to the customers would have revealed the problem. If that doesn’t teach a lesson…

Thank you for not understanding my Problem @Holger
I decompiled the code to review it and THEN created my local env.

So you're saying the code immediately below i tried adding some debugging code for testing in the Java Code, so it would look like this : is the result of decompilation?

I don’t see how it matter whether you decompiled the code to test it. The point is, this code is so fundamentally broken that testing it just a single time would have revealed the problem and now your company is paying the price for deploying entirely untested software to the customers.

Thank you guys for helping me out !
Answers are :
The available() method is not intended to do what you want to do with it. There is no way to setup the php software to make the method do what you want. If you want to save the content of an InputStream to a local file, just use Files.copy, if you want read it into a byte array, use is.readAllBytes() –
Holger
WebClient.doRawRequest() will send the request to the server and immediately return the InputStream. Since the InputStream will only have data available once the server has processed the request and delivered data a call to is.available() will return 0 (since at that moment reading data will block). There is nothing you can do on the PHP side to change this. –
Thomas Kläger
Im trying to close this topic now.
